# How to add a REST API to the Modern Web Dev Server?

Tags: javascript, backend, devserver

I'm using the dev-server of [Modern Web](https://modern-web.dev/) to build client side code.
Now I want to add a small backend with a REST API, but I can't find any information of how to add a backend with a REST API to this server.
Any hints on where to start?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You *could* [write a plugin for it](https://modern-web.dev/docs/dev-server/writing-plugins/overview/) but I wouldn't recommend it.

It's a development server designed for testing client-side code.

It isn't designed to be a production server, and if you are going to write a REST API then you will, presumably, want it to be usable in a production environment.

Build your API with a tool designed for it (such as Express.js or Spring Boot) and use CORS to make it accessible to the server you use for client-side development.